# localStorage not storing persistently between two pages

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I'm developing an application and, at certain point, I need to store information that requires to be persistent between multiple pages, more probably, it will only be 2 pages.
The amount of information varies between just a few bytes and about 15KB (It will never be more than 20KB, ever). I can't really properly predict beforehand how much it will be.

For that I decided to use localStorage.

For now I'm only working on localhost:8080.

The pages, for now have only generic names: pageA.php and pageB.php.

The pages reside on the root of the domain. I.e.

```
http://localhost:8080/pageA.php
http://localhost:8080/pageB.php
```

...

At certain times, I store data on localStorage, on pageA.php (I do use the setItem() method).

When the user moves to pageB.php, pageB.php's script then tries to get the data that was stored in pageA.php.
The problem is that getItem() always returns null on pageB.php

I did check the keys I'm using and they are the same, so there should be no problems there.

I've checked, data stored is persisting between page loads as long as the url does not change.

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: tested only on Firefox 19 and on chrome 24

Comment: Might be preaching to the choir, but just in case this helps you: In Chrome's developer tools (and I presume there's a FireBug equivalent) you can monitor what's in local storage. Right click your page, select "Inspect Element", then under the "Resources" tab you'll find "Local Storage" in the resources tree.

Comment: Thank you. That allowed me to find what I was doing wrong. I wonder why I forgot about such feature on chrome :D.

Comment: My pleasure mate.  Almost didn't write it in case you flamed me for pointing out the bleeding obvious! ;-)  Would you mind self-answering your question with whatever problem/solution you found, so that this post might help someone else in future?

Comment: Meh... ok. You did put yourself some work on writting that comment back, so... yeah... ok.

Comment: I think you can probably accept your own answer now... ;-)

Comment: @Sepster Yeah... sounds about right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that the editor I was using had been changed such that it was searching with case sensitivity.
When I changed the string i was using for the key, the replacer didn't match all the strings due to case sensivity.
I solved it by searching and adapting each key such that all keys had the same characters with the same case, not the same characters regardless of case.
In the in the end, it was just lack of attention. As expected, **strings in javascript are case sensitive and that also applies to the key for localStorage and sessionStorage**

Comment: +1 D'oh! Can I recommend rather than using literal strings for your key, you use (psuedo) constants for your key, this way they're defined literally only the once, thus avoiding failures caused by typos or case. eg `var LSK_SOMEKEYNAME = "SomeKeyName";` (LSK = local storage key).  This approach should really apply _anywhere_ in your code that you're using some literal constant in your code (not just string literals); it helps to avoid this issue, and adds meaning to your code (eg `lineNum = lineNum +2` becomes `lineNum = lineNum + LINE_OFFSET_DUE_TO_BLANK_LINES`).